# how to make this shape as look like filter?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]

The knife tool could not help to remove not required path given shape. Is there are tools in Adobe Illustrator which might help to make this shape much more perfect.

1. at bottom, half of the ellipse should be removed to get the perfect filter shape.
2. the joining lines from above and bottom ellipse are not connected as per my wish, the corners from the lines are visible and during zoom, it appears clearly.

**Goal** is to make this type of filter graphic: [image: goal_graphic]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have Smart Guides and Snap to point ON (no other snaps) to get the line ends placed perfctly on the nodes of the ellipses.

Having rounded line ends will hide the unwanted corners at the ends.

Learn to use the Shape Builder to make closed areas when the borders are drawn OK. An example:

[image]

In the left is your initial shape.

In the middle all is selected and the Shape Builder is just dragged over the seam which should vanish.

In the right both areas are filled. The fill is a simple gradient.

Also learn the tool options and know that

- the tool can also be used for removing parts
- grouped items generate groups which must be ungrouped for edits
- there's often unwanted tailings (extra parts from extended lines) which must be deleted
- keep spare copies, since the tool is destructive
- The Shaper tool and the Live Paint Bucket can be often used instead of the Shape Builder. They work non-destructively.

**Not asked**: If a realistic look is wanted the amount of needed work will increase and a beginner can easily get stuck. Fortunately Illustrator has 3D effects which can create some elementary forms with very little effort by revolving and extruding. 3D shading is made automatically and texts & images on the surface get the right projection often with zero effort.

These are no substitute for 3D design programs but they can be used for easy projection and shading as long as revolve and extrude are enough. An example:

[image]